# Issue getting functions from library and strange conversion error

Tags: c++, constructor, arduino, static-libraries

I'm trying to write an arduino library. I've written a few classes before but nothing for arduino. I'm running into one error pretty consistently. First let me show you the code:

## Code

Main.ino (The arduino project)

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include "Mobility.h"

Mobility mol = new Mobility();
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Wire.begin();
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("loop");
  mol.move(true, 125, false, 125, 10);
  delay(2000);
}
```

Mobility.h

```
#ifndef MOBILITY_H
#define MOBILITY_H

#if (ARDUINO >= 100)
 #include "Arduino.h"
#else
 #include "WProgram.h"
#endif


const int DEFAULT_MOBILITY_ADD  = 4;

class Mobility
{
public:
    void begin();
    void begin(int address);
    int i2cAdd;
    int move(bool lPos, unsigned char leftPower, bool rPos, unsigned char rightPower, unsigned char msec);
private:

};
/**/
#endif
```

Mobility.cpp

```
#if (ARDUINO >= 100)
 #include "Arduino.h"
#else
 #include "WProgram.h"
#endif
#include "Mobility.h"
#include "Wire.h"


void Mobility::begin(){
    Wire.begin();
    this.i2cAdd = DEFAULT_MOBILITY_ADD;
}

void Mobility::begin(int address){
    Wire.begin();
    this.i2cAdd = address;
}

int Mobility::move(bool lPos, unsigned char leftPower,bool rPos, unsigned char rightPower, unsigned char msec){
  if (leftPower < -255 || leftPower > 255){
    return -1;
  }
  if (rightPower < -255 || rightPower > 255){
    return -2;
  }
  if(msec <= 0){
    return -3;
  }

  Wire.beginTransmission(this.i2cAdd);
  Wire.write(lPos);
  Wire.write(leftPower);
  Wire.write(rPos);
  Wire.write(rightPower);
  Wire.write(msec);
  Wire.endTransmission();
  return 0;
}
```

## ERRORS

I've been getting two big errors while I've been trying to fix the code. The first is:
    error: conversion from 'Mobility*' to non-scalar type 'Mobility' requested
     Mobility mol = new Mobility();

Comment: a `Mobility` is not a `Mobility*`. one is an object the other is a pointer

Comment: btw you dont need all this code to reproduce this error. Just try to understand, why `int main() { int a = new int(23);}` cannot work and you will also know why you get the error in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by this line:

```
 Mobility mol = new Mobility();
```

the first part is static memory allocation:`Mobility mol` - statically allocates memory for the object `mol`.

the second part uses dynamic memory allocation: `new` - dynamically allocates memory.

So you can do :

```
Mobility mol;// static allocation
```

or

```
Mobility *mol = new Mobility(); //dynamic allcocation
```

But not a mix of the two. Either way the constructor will be called when creating the object.